# ng-model in <dropdownlist> and <input type="text"> Angularjs / HTML / Nodejs / REST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am using one $scope.sample variable to receive ng-model from two input fields. It is working fine. I do this: ng-model="sample.first" and ng-model="sample.second".
Then, I tried to remove the first input and use a dropdownlist instead. The dropdownlist is filled by a different variable $scope.list using the ng-model="list". The dropdownlist is filled correctly. However, I need to put the selected item in the dropdownlist to the $scope variable sample.first. This is not working. How can I do this?

Thank you,

Rafael

Comment: Please edit your question to include code snippets, more verbose explanations, the point of your code, and grammar fixes. As it reads now, it is impossible to understand what you need help with

Comment: You changed the name of one variable to a different name, and now the new variable can't save into the old variable name? what?

Comment: wouldn't you populate the list with `ng-options`?

Comment: No way we can help without seeing how ng-options is set up and a data sample

Comment: Sorry. First, I have this: a form-group with two input DOM. One with ng-model="sample.second" and another with ng-model="sample.first". This is on the template side. On the controller side I have this: $scope.sample={}. Then, When the user writes something in both input fields, I post the  $scope.sample={} through REST CRUD. After that, I check and see that both inputs were stored on my database.

Comment: However, I need the whole thing with only one input field and one dropdowlist. Trying to implement this last, I did this: on the template side I removed one input field (the one with sample.first) to put a dropdownlist instead. Within the select DOM I used ng-model="list" and ng-options. On the controller side, I did this: $scope.sample = {} and $scope.list={item:"name"}. I would like to be able to pass the selected item on the dropdownlist  to sample.first in order to post my $scope.sample={} to my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with :

```
##### <select ng-model="sample.first">
        <option ng-repeat="list in lists" value="{{list.name}}">{{list.name}}</option>
      </select>   #### Using  $scope.lists= [{name: "Joe"}] on the controller.
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular to do a select element, you would use this syntax:

```
<select ng-model="sample.first" ng-options="item.property for item in list"></select>
```

Where "item" is simply an object in your $scope.list array. The select should be properly filled and when an item is selected, it will set that item as your ng-model value, "sample.first".

Comment: Thank you. I typed the ng-options like "item.property for item in list" on my select DOM. Is this correct? I am asking because it is not filling out de dropdown.

Comment: Do you know how to implement using this kind of dropdown:                              #####<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <h1>Dropdown Select</h1>
        <p>You have selected: {{ddSelectSelected}}</p>
        <div dropdown-select="ddSelectOptions"
            dropdown-model="ddSelectSelected"
            dropdown-item-label="text" >
        </div> 
    </div>  ####